# Node.js: How to search for modules that have a specified field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, require

**Main**: How do i require modules that have `example` field in it's `package.json`?

For example:

```
const path = require( "path" );
const glob = require( "glob" );

const modules = glob.sync( './node_modules/*' );

for ( let mod in modules ) {
    const modPackage = require( path.resolve( __dirname, "node_modules", mod, "package.json" ) );
    if ( modPackage.hasOwnProperty( "example" ) ) {
        console.log( "Module:", mod, "Has Field 'example'" );
    }
}
```

**Addiotinal**: How do i require modules that have a specific tag? (for example: "demo")

Comment: your question is ambiguous , what you grammatically as in the name, is that you want a search in package.json for a particular file but you do not want to invoke that file. please elaborate

Comment: I fixed it. but you read entire content for main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is basically correct, just two issues:

1. You wanted `for-of`, not `for-in`.
2. No need to add `/node_modules/` to the path.

So:

```
const path = require( "path" );
const glob = require( "glob" );

const modules = glob.sync( './node_modules/*' );

for (let mod of modules ) {
// ----------^^
    const modPackage = require( path.resolve( __dirname, mod, "package.json" ) );
// ------------------------------------------------------^
    if ( modPackage.hasOwnProperty( "example" ) ) {
        console.log( "Module:", mod, "Has Field 'example'" );
    }
}
```

You almost never want to use `for-in` on arrays. More about looping through arrays in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).

Comment: No, the code is just example that i was written. i need best practice to do it.

Comment: @HasanBayat: I don't see a problem with the above. How else would you do it? I mean, you could use `readFile` and `JSON.parse` instead of `require`, but...

Comment: Is there any package that do it?